# Loading python TensorFlow Layers models into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, webpack, tensorflow.js

The core `TensorFlow` libraries provide the ability to convert a model created in `Python` to be saved into a `JSON` file describing the graph and weights to be executed in a browser environment.

In the examples you are required to load the whole `TensorFlow` library in the browser, which is extremely heavy. Also tree shaking is not available for this library.

My question is: how would I load just the necessary elements from `TensorFlow JS` into the client/browser to reduce the overall size of my bundled application?

EDIT: We are trying to reduce the over size of the bundled library.

Comment: The size of the [tf.js script](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js) is 813KB, 190KB gzipped. Do you consider 190KB "extremely heavy" or do you mean something else?

Comment: Ok it is subjective, but yes in my use case this is heavy and needs to be reduced.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf any help?

Comment: Added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The Tensorflow.js API combines four packages:

- [tfjs-core](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-core): Functionality like mathematical functions and backend support
- [tfjs-layers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-layers): Support of layers to create models (depends on `tfjs-core`)
- [tfjs-data](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-data): Data handling (depends on `tfjs-core`)
- [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter): Support for converting models to Tensorflow.js

Depending on what tasks exactly you need to perform, it might be sufficent to only use some of the packages. That said, keep in mind that `tfjs-layers` and `tfjs-data` require `tfjs-core` to be imported.

**Code Sample**

The following lines only import the Core and Layers API:

```js
import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import * as tfl from '@tensorflow/tfjs-layers';

// Examples how to use the APIs
const vectr = tfc.tensor(/* .. */);
const model = tfl.sequential();
const dense = tfl.layers.dense(/* .. */);
```

Note that functions like [`tf.matMul`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#matMul) are used by calling `tfc.matMul`, but some functions of the layers API (like [`tf.layers.dense`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.dense)) are used by calling `tfl.layers.dense` while others (like [`tf.sequential`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#sequential)) are used by calling `tfl.sequential`.

**Optimization**

To give you an idea on the potential optimization, let's look at the numbers:

```
--------------------------------------
|     Package    |  Size  | Relative |
|----------------|--------|----------|
| tfjs           |    856 |     100% |
| tfjs-core      |    506 |      59% |
| tfjs-layers    |    228 |      27% |
| tfjs-data      |     52 |       6% |
| tfjs-converter |     80 |       9% |
--------------------------------------
```

<sub>Version 1.2.7, Size in KB (of the minified JS file), relative values compared to tfjs</sub>

Using `tfjs-core` and `tfjs-layers` directly, it is possible to shrink the size by 122 KB or 14%. If you need more than that you can always try to rebuild the repository on your own, removing any unneeded functionality. Of course, this approach would mean a lot of manual work.

**Tree Shaking**

As you already noticed yourself, tree shaking is currently not supported, but you might want to follow the discussion for [support of tree-shaking](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/353) in the tfjs github repository regarding that topic.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas however I am already doing this - I really feel that since building the model in python, to then use it to predict, is really a case of storing a matrix of weights and a few simple multiplication ops - there is lots of room for optimisation here.

Comment: @dendog As I have written, the only option I see (while tree-shaking is not supported) is to rebuild the repository yourself and reduce unused code (manually).